# Looking for open source web applications written in Sinatra (with or without MongoDB)

Tags: web-applications, open-source, mongodb, sinatra

I learn well by example, so I would love it if someone could point me to a site/list/technique for finding a few varied web apps written in Sinatra, particularly with MongoMapper.

I have tried, with mixed results, googling for:

- [site:github.com "require sinatra"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3agithub.com+%22require+sinatra%22)
- [site:github.com "built on sinatra"](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3agithub.com+%22built+on+sinatra%22&hl=en)

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Why do you need to learn sinatra?  The sinatra website itself has a ton of examples http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html

Comment: Yes, the sinatra website has some toy examples.  But I am looking for real, decent-sized web applications, in the wild, which are written on Sinatra.

Comment: Also, if you believe my question's not appropriate for Stack Overflow, please point me to some more appropriate StackExchange site, and I'll gladly move it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with quotes's around it .

[site:github.com "require 'sinatra'"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Agithub+%22require+%27sinatra%27%22#q=site%3agithub.com+%22require+%27sinatra%27%22&hl=en&prmd=ivns&ei=kcQ8TZi7F4rmsQOzhcixAw&start=10&sa=N&fp=25a0b2344dc0e416)

Comment: This gives basically the same results, but what variation I get is nice.  +1 since I didn't know google would honor *any* symbol literals :)

Comment: quotes around things make google see anything within them as literals that you want to search on, otherwise it tends to throw out any symbols.